# No Scaffold widget found when use BottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am just learning Flutter and got stuck on this error:

```
No Scaffold widget found.

Home widgets require a Scaffold widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a Scaffold ancestor was: Home
The ancestors of this widget were
```

but as you can see from my code I do have a Scaffold and I played around adding it wherever I can but I didn't work for.

What can be the reason to what I've done or didn't notice there?

```
import 'package:firebase_redux_app/services/firebase.auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_redux_app/services/firestore.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_redux_app/screens/home/brewList.dart';
import 'package:firebase_redux_app/models/brew.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _showSettingsPanel() {
      showBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 60.0),
              child: Text('bottom sheet'),
            );
          });
    }

    return StreamProvider<List<Brew>>.value(
      value: DBFirestore().brews,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Brew Crew'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
          elevation: 0.0,
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton.icon(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await _auth.signOut();
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: Text('Log Out')),
            FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              label: Text('settings'),
              onPressed: () => _showSettingsPanel(),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: BrewList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is caused because of the scope of your `_showSettingsPanel` method

There are 2 things you can do

***1.***
Make the `_showSettingsPanel` a method in the `Home` class and allow it take the context as a parameter. Hence, wrap your *settings* `FlatButton` in a `Builder` and pass the `context` to the `_showSettingsPanel` method.

Like this

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  void _showSettingsPanel(context) {
    showBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 60.0),
            child: Text('bottom sheet'),
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Brew>>(
      value: DBFireStore().brews
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Brew Crew'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
          elevation: 0.0,
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton.icon(
                onPressed: () async {
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: Text('Log Out')),
            Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                return FlatButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                  label: Text('settings'),
                  onPressed: () => _showSettingsPanel(context),
                );
              }
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: BrewList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***2.***
Wrap the `Home` widget in a `Scaffold` wherever you use it, instead of using just `Home`

Like this

```
Scaffold(body: Home())
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I couldn't get why it's like that so I even played around with Scaffold and put it everywhere I could)) Both your ways worked well!

Comment: if you don't mind I'd like to ask some more questions on flutter... It would be great to hear an experienced programmer. Flutter and Dart are new for me and I'm a bit puzzled about state management and Streams. If you ever worked with RxJS library,

Comment: 1) do Streams in Flutter the same things but you just shouldn't subscribe to them like in RxJS? Are there any memory leaks?

Comment: 2) responsiveness in design for different devices. Is there any grid system for that? Maybe a silly question but maybe there are some best practices for that.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get the first question...

For responsive design, there are widgets like LayoutBuilder, MediaQuery, Wrap, OrientationBuilder etc. to help build Responsive UIs.

The Grid responsive system can't be implemented with Wrap. or LayoutBuilder and Grid.

Comment: if you ever used RxJS you should unsubscribe from the stream before you destroy the component otherwise you'll have a memory leak (stream will flow endlessly and may also affect to the logic, and the app speed fall dramatically because unused streams eat memory) That's what I meant in my first question. Should I unsubscribe from those streams or it's done under the hood bt the framework? though, In Flutter I don't explicitly subscribe to them.

Comment: Sorry I meant the Grid system can be implemented with Wrap or LayoutBuilder and Grid not ***can't***

Comment: maybe you have a minute to help me out with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578644/cannot-set-state-outside-a-container-in-provider

Answer (score 1):

now this prb has different solutions. U gotta use sccafoldKey

```dart
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  return Scaffold(
     key: _scaffoldKey,
     appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _scaffoldKey.currentState!.showBottomSheet(
                          (context) => const AddTaskScreen());
               },
               icon: const Icon(Icons.add))
            ],
          ),
```