# Cannot set state outside a Container in Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, provider

I understand that the problem is in a lifecircle that I'm trying to set a state in Provider before the Widget is rendered but where can I do that. Only in a Container Widget? But I cannot do that unless I've a button or something.

I hope you got the issue of the problem here.

I would appreciate any hints!

my Error:

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

or

```
The setter 'lastPage=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: lastPage=true
```

if I set the state in here

```
  _detectLastPage() {
    int currentPage = this.currentStep == null ? 1 : this.currentStep + 1;

    if (currentPage == 1 && this.currentStep == null) {
      this._onFirstPage();
    } else if (currentPage == this.totalSteps) {
      this.lastPage = true;
      _welcomeBloc.lastPage = true;
      this._onLastPage();
    } else {
      this.lastPage = false;
      _welcomeBloc.lastPage = true;
    }
  }
```

My Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:ui_flutter/screens/welcome/welcome_bloc.dart';

class Footer extends StatelessWidget {
  final int currentStep;
  final int totalSteps;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color inactiveColor;
  final Duration duration;
  final Function onFinal;
  final Function onStart;

  final double radius = 10.0;
  final double distance = 4.0;

  Container stepper;
  Container nextArrow;
  bool lastPage;
  WelcomeBloc _welcomeBloc;

  Footer({
    this.activeColor,
    this.inactiveColor,
    this.currentStep,
    this.totalSteps,
    this.duration,
    this.onFinal,
    this.onStart,
  }) {
    this._detectLastPage();
    this._makeStepper();
    this._makeNextArrow();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('footer is launching');

    final WelcomeBloc _welcome = Provider.of<WelcomeBloc>(context);
    _welcomeBloc = _welcome;
    // this._welcomeBloc.lastPage = true; // I'd like to set the state here

    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0, horizontal: 30.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          this.stepper,
          this.nextArrow,
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('kdfljds'),
            onPressed: () {
              print(_welcomeBloc.lastPage);
              _welcomeBloc.lastPage = true; // I can access from here BUT CANNOT access outside this container
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeCirle(activeColor, inactiveColor, position, currentStep) {
    currentStep = currentStep ?? 0;
    Color color = (position == currentStep) ? activeColor : inactiveColor;

    return Container(
      height: this.radius,
      width: this.radius,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: this.distance, right: this.distance),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          border: Border.all(color: activeColor, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
    );
  }

  _makeStepper() {
    List<Container> circles = List();

    for (var i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++) {
      circles.add(
        _makeCirle(this.activeColor, this.inactiveColor, i, this.currentStep),
      );
    }

    this.stepper = Container(
      child: Row(
        children: circles,
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeNextArrow() {
    this.nextArrow = Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              _welcomeBloc.controller.nextPage(
                duration: this.duration ?? Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
              );
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onLastPage() {
    if (this.onFinal != null) {
      this.onFinal();
    }
  }

  _onFirstPage() {
    if (this.onStart != null) {
      this.onStart();
    }
  }

  _detectLastPage() {
    int currentPage = this.currentStep == null ? 1 : this.currentStep + 1;

    if (currentPage == 1 && this.currentStep == null) {
      this._onFirstPage();
    } else if (currentPage == this.totalSteps) {
      this.lastPage = true;
      this._onLastPage();
    } else {
      this.lastPage = false;
    }
  }
}
```

BlocFile

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WelcomeBloc extends ChangeNotifier {

  PageController _controller = PageController();
  int _currentPage;
  bool _lastPage = false;

  bool get lastPage => _lastPage; 

  set lastPage(bool value){
    print(value);
    _lastPage = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get currentPage => _currentPage;

  set currentPage(int value) {
    _currentPage = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  get controller => _controller;

  nextPage(Duration duration, Curves curve){
    controller.nextPage(duration: duration, curve: curve);
  }
}
```

```
[![error screen with StateLess, since I use Provider][1]][1]
```

[image: That's In a StateFul Widget]

There I call like this:

```
_detectLastPage() {
    int currentPage =
        this.widget.currentStep == null ? 1 : this.widget.currentStep + 1;

    if (currentPage == 1 && this.widget.currentStep == null) {
      this._onFirstPage();
    } else if (currentPage == this.widget.totalSteps) {
      this.lastPage = true;
      setState(() {
        _welcomeBloc.lastPage = true;
      });
      this._onLastPage();
    } else {
      this.lastPage = false;
      setState(() {
        _welcomeBloc.lastPage = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

[image: StateLess]
And without SetState seem to be the same error...

this error if I call from inside initState from your example. Just forgot you attach it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `setState` method in a `StatelessWidget`. Convert it to a `StatefulWidget` and call the `setState` in the `initState` method.

Like this

```
class Footer extends StatefulWidget {
  final int currentStep;
  final int totalSteps;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color inactiveColor;
  final Duration duration;
  final Function onFinal;
  final Function onStart;

  Footer({
    this.activeColor,
    this.inactiveColor,
    this.currentStep,
    this.totalSteps,
    this.duration,
    this.onFinal,
    this.onStart,
  });

  @override
  _FooterState createState() => _FooterState();
}


class _FooterState extends State<Footer> {


  final double radius = 10.0;
  final double distance = 4.0;

  Container stepper;
  Container nextArrow;
  bool lastPage;
  WelcomeBloc _welcomeBloc;

  @override
  void initState(){
    this._detectLastPage();
    this._makeStepper();
    this._makeNextArrow();
    final WelcomeBloc _welcome = Provider.of<WelcomeBloc>(context);
    _welcomeBloc = _welcome;
    setState((){
     this._welcomeBloc.lastPage = true; // Where to use setState
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('footer is launching');


    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0, horizontal: 30.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          this.stepper,
          this.nextArrow,
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('kdfljds'),
            onPressed: () {
              print(_welcomeBloc.lastPage);
              _welcomeBloc.lastPage = true; // I can access from here BUT CANNOT access outside this container
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeCirle(activeColor, inactiveColor, position, currentStep) {
    currentStep = currentStep ?? 0;
    Color color = (position == currentStep) ? activeColor : inactiveColor;

    return Container(
      height: this.radius,
      width: this.radius,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: this.distance, right: this.distance),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          border: Border.all(color: activeColor, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
    );
  }

  _makeStepper() {
    List<Container> circles = List();

    for (var i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++) {
      circles.add(
        _makeCirle(this.activeColor, this.inactiveColor, i, this.currentStep),
      );
    }

    this.stepper = Container(
      child: Row(
        children: circles,
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeNextArrow() {
    this.nextArrow = Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              _welcomeBloc.controller.nextPage(
                duration: this.duration ?? Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
              );
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onLastPage() {
    if (this.onFinal != null) {
      this.onFinal();
    }
  }

  _onFirstPage() {
    if (this.onStart != null) {
      this.onStart();
    }
  }

  _detectLastPage() {
    int currentPage = this.currentStep == null ? 1 : this.currentStep + 1;

    if (currentPage == 1 && this.currentStep == null) {
      this._onFirstPage();
    } else if (currentPage == this.totalSteps) {
      this.lastPage = true;
      this._onLastPage();
    } else {
      this.lastPage = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I tried it. It doesn't help. I've got some other errors instead

Comment: I am not setting a local state but setting the state in Provider vie setter. I'll update it with my other other

Comment: /flutter ( 4834): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(540.0,
I/flutter ( 4834): 960.0), devicePixelRatio: 2.0, textScaleFactor: 1.0, platformBrightness: Brightness.light, padding:
I/flutter ( 4834): EdgeInsets.zero, viewPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero, physicalDepth:
I/flutter ( 4834): 1.7976931348623157e+308, alwaysUse24HourFormat: true, accessibleNavigation: false, highContrast:
I/flutter ( 4834): false,disableAnimations: false, invertColors: false, boldText: false)):

Comment: Interesting thing is that I can update the state inside Container Widget but outside it all the time error. I am not still used to the patterns in Flutter and after Angular and Vue it's still puzzling :/

Comment: Just in short what I'm gonna do is  - I've got a footer Widget and a Wrapper which holds fotter, pageViewer and header. I need when I reach my last page (footer is responsible for that) it changes the state in my state management file WelcomeBloc (I am trying to implement it vie Provider to learn it). as soon as it's updated I need to react to that in my Wrapper widget and hide header and footer.

Comment: What am I doing wrong here?)) Thanks for helping me again with Flutter!

Comment: Can you snap the error upload it and drop the link here?

Comment: Both Errrors are there... there must be a very silly mistake but I am not just aware of that)) and don't see it...

Comment: Updated with the screen of the error if I call from initState

Comment: Any ideas about it?

Comment: Huh............nope.....Did you notifyListeners in your ChangeNotifier?

Comment: Yes, I did as you can see above in my welcomebloc file... Or I did something wrong there...

Comment: You do not need setState

Comment: Remove setState and try again

Comment: But as a StatefulWidget

Comment: Yes, I did try to do that but it didn't work as well

Comment: it must be a simple task but i'm stuck here)) not my day

Comment: I have moved on a bit further with that  problem. If you have a second dart a look :) at my other question, please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61598767/didchangedependencies-hook-in-flutter-widget-includes-not-accurate-data-of-the-c

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right you are trying to simulate `PageView` navigation by some circle bellow it(Indicators).

To do so there are lots of good resources and also packages like:
[This example](https://gist.github.com/collinjackson/4fddbfa2830ea3ac033e34622f278824) or [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/page_view_indicators)

But for your code I wrote it in 2 approaches:

**First Approach**

This one is your code and use provider.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Home());
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => WelcomeBloc(),
      child: Consumer<WelcomeBloc>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget child) {
          PageController controller = value.controller;
          print('object');
          return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
              body: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  PageView(
                    controller: controller,
                    children: List.generate(
                        10, (i) => Center(child: Text('Page $i'))),
                    onPageChanged: (i) {
                      value.currentPage = i;
                    },
                  ),
                  Footer(
                    activeColor: Colors.red,
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    inactiveColor: Colors.yellow,
                    onFinal: () {},
                    onStart: () {},
                    totalSteps: 10,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Footer extends StatefulWidget {
  final int totalSteps;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color inactiveColor;
  final Duration duration;
  final Function onFinal;
  final Function onStart;
  final double radius;
  final double distance;

  Footer({
    this.activeColor,
    this.inactiveColor,
    this.totalSteps,
    this.duration,
    this.onFinal,
    this.onStart,
    this.radius = 10.0,
    this.distance = 4.0,
  });

  @override
  _FooterState createState() => _FooterState();
}

class _FooterState extends State<Footer> {
  bool lastPage;
  WelcomeBloc _welcomeBloc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final WelcomeBloc _welcome = Provider.of<WelcomeBloc>(context);

    _welcomeBloc = _welcome;

    // this._welcomeBloc.lastPage = true; // I'd like to set the state here

    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0, horizontal: 30.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          _makeStepper(),
          _makeNextArrow(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeCircle(activeColor, inactiveColor, position, currentStep) {
    currentStep = currentStep ?? 0;
    Color color = (position == currentStep) ? activeColor : inactiveColor;

    return Container(
      height: widget.radius,
      width: widget.radius,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: widget.distance, right: widget.distance),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          border: Border.all(color: activeColor, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
    );
  }

  _makeNextArrow() {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              await _welcomeBloc.nextPage(widget.duration, Curves.easeInOut);
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeStepper() {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: List.generate(
          widget.totalSteps,
          (i) => _makeCircle(
            this.widget.activeColor,
            this.widget.inactiveColor,
            i,
            _welcomeBloc.currentPage,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onLastPage() {
    if (this.widget.onFinal != null) {
      this.widget.onFinal();
    }
  }

  _onFirstPage() {
    if (this.widget.onStart != null) {
      this.widget.onStart();
    }
  }

  _detectLastPage() {
    int currentPage =
        _welcomeBloc.currentPage == null ? 1 : _welcomeBloc.currentPage + 1;

    if (currentPage == 1 && _welcomeBloc.currentPage == null) {
      this._onFirstPage();
    } else if (currentPage == this.widget.totalSteps) {
      this.lastPage = true;
      this._onLastPage();
    } else {
      this.lastPage = false;
    }
  }
}

class WelcomeBloc extends ChangeNotifier {
  final PageController _controller = PageController();
  int _currentPage = 0;
  bool _lastPage = false;

  bool get lastPage => _lastPage;

  set lastPage(bool value) {
    _lastPage = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get currentPage => _currentPage;

  set currentPage(int value) {
    _currentPage = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  PageController get controller => _controller;

  Future<void> nextPage(Duration duration, Curve curve) {
    currentPage = controller.page.floor() + 1;
    return controller.nextPage(duration: duration, curve: curve);
  }
}
```

**Second Approach**

In the second one I removed provider stuff because it can be done without it by using `PageController` features.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Home());
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            PageView(
              controller: controller,
              children: List.generate(
                10,
                (i) => Center(child: Text('Page $i')),
              ),
              onPageChanged: (page) {
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
            Footer(
              currentPage: controller.hasClients ? controller.page.floor() : 0,
              activeColor: Colors.red,
              inactiveColor: Colors.yellow,
              totalSteps: 10,
              onTap: () async {
                await controller.nextPage(
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 1) ?? Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                );
                setState(() {});
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Footer extends StatelessWidget {
  final int totalSteps;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color inactiveColor;
  final double radius;
  final double distance;
  final int currentPage;
  final GestureTapCallback onTap;

  Footer({
    this.activeColor,
    this.inactiveColor,
    this.totalSteps,
    this.radius = 10.0,
    this.distance = 4.0,
    this.currentPage,
    this.onTap,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0, horizontal: 30.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          _makeStepper(),
          _makeNextArrow(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeCircle(activeColor, inactiveColor, position) {
    Color color = (position == currentPage) ? activeColor : inactiveColor;

    return Container(
      height: radius,
      width: radius,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: distance, right: distance),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          border: Border.all(color: activeColor, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
    );
  }

  _makeNextArrow() {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: onTap,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeStepper() {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: List.generate(
          totalSteps,
          (i) => _makeCircle(
            this.activeColor,
            this.inactiveColor,
            i,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I found many different libraries for indicating the current page but I just wanted to work on my skills and tried to do it by myself) I've ended up with a bit different structure than I showed up here... Thanks for your approaches. I am still lost with Glocalkey, PageComtroller and others. I've just put my PageContoller in a StateBloc and grab it from there whenever I need it. Maybe that's not a good approach but it worked for me)) The problem I faced in the code above is that I updated page state in my build block and `didChangeDependencies ` invoked earlier. One step behind always :/

Comment: I am curious about different ways to set a State outside the Widget block. Because I struggled for a long time with the error `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`

Comment: `List.generate` - this is very handy))

Comment: I couldn't fully get your problem with `didChangeDependencies`, but if you use bloc and also use `setState` it invoke such errors because you should use `StreamBuilder` to redraw your widgets.

Comment: Also if your widget is `StatefulWidget` and you use `initState` for some prebuild stuff, you should use `didUpdateWidget` too. for example when you send some data and those data change in a bloc before calling this widget.[Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20416#issuecomment-412013107) are more info.

Comment: Yes, my question was mutating on-the-go... it's solid and clear there. I agree)) but it started with the setState problem. Just to sum up the question. What is the way to change the state (no matter its a provider or set state because they both update UI and bring in `SetState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.` error? I've found only two possible ways: before and after build block with the help of `didChangeDependencies ` - before and `Future.microtask` - after. any other attempts ended up with an error

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution of my error is in `didChangeDependencies` hook.

I tried to change the state above at the very moment when the Widget was being built (that's how I got it).

So, I just needed to run it either before or after widget is built.

That's how it looks like in the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:ui_flutter/screens/welcome/welcome_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class Footer extends StatefulWidget {
  final int currentStep;
  final int totalSteps;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color inactiveColor;
  final Duration duration;
  final Function onFinal;
  final Function onStart;

  Footer({
    this.activeColor,
    this.inactiveColor,
    this.currentStep,
    this.totalSteps,
    this.duration,
    this.onFinal,
    this.onStart,
  }) {}

  @override
  _FooterState createState() => _FooterState();
}

class _FooterState extends State<Footer> {
  final double radius = 10.0;
  final double distance = 4.0;
  Container stepper;
  Container nextArrow;
  bool lastPage;
  WelcomeBloc _welcomeBloc;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    final WelcomeBloc _welcome = Provider.of<WelcomeBloc>(context);
    _welcomeBloc = _welcome;
    this._detectLastPage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this._makeStepper();
    this._makeNextArrow();

    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0, horizontal: 30.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          this.stepper,
          this.nextArrow,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeCirle(activeColor, inactiveColor, position, currentStep) {
    currentStep = currentStep == null ? 0 : currentStep - 1;
    Color color = (position == currentStep) ? activeColor : inactiveColor;

    return Container(
      height: this.radius,
      width: this.radius,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: this.distance, right: this.distance),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          border: Border.all(color: activeColor, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
    );
  }

  _makeStepper() {
    List<Container> circles = List();

    for (var i = 0; i < widget.totalSteps; i++) {
      circles.add(
        _makeCirle(this.widget.activeColor, this.widget.inactiveColor, i,
            this.widget.currentStep),
      );
    }

    this.stepper = Container(
      child: Row(
        children: circles,
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeNextArrow() {
    this.nextArrow = Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              _welcomeBloc.controller.nextPage(
                duration: this.widget.duration ?? Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
              );
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onLastPage() {
    if (this.widget.onFinal != null) {
      this.widget.onFinal();
    }
  }

  _onFirstPage() {
    if (this.widget.onStart != null) {
      this.widget.onStart();
    }
  }

  _detectLastPage() {
    // Here I've got inaccurate data 

    int currentPage =
        this.widget.currentStep == null ? 1 : this.widget.currentStep;

    if (currentPage == 1 && this.widget.currentStep == null) {
      this._onFirstPage();
    } else if (currentPage == this.widget.totalSteps) {
      print('lastPage detected');
      setState(() {
        this.lastPage = true;
      });
      _welcomeBloc.lastPage = true;
      this._onLastPage();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        this.lastPage = false;
      });
      _welcomeBloc.lastPage = false;
    }
  }
}
```

P.S.: but I face another problem there with the data accuracy. Inside that hook I could get the class property only one step behind accurate one.

- details here: [didChangeDependencies hook in Flutter Widget includes not accurate data of the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61598767/didchangedependencies-hook-in-flutter-widget-includes-not-accurate-data-of-the-c)