# didChangeDependencies hook in Flutter Widget includes not accurate data of the class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

In my code below, I am struggling with LifeCyrles in Flutter where I can update my State in Provider, APPARENTLY, only in `didChangeDependencies` hook or in a template widget (via events hung up on buttons or so).

Alright, I don't mind that only didChangeDependencies hook works for me BUT when my logic in earlier mentioned hook depends on some class properties I am having problems with the accuracy of the class data. 
I get data one step behind (since it's called before `build` hook I guess).

I cannot run this logic in the build hook because it includes a request to change the state in Provider. If I try to change the state there I've got either this error:

`setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`

or this one

`The setter 'lastPage=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: lastPage=true`

**What I want to do**: I've got a wrapper widget which holds three other widgets: footer, header and pageViewer. 
When I reach the last page I need to notify my wrapper widget about that so it reacts accordingly and hides header and footer.

I would appreciate any help here!

The focused code:

*Here is the problem and must be solution*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:ui_flutter/screens/welcome/welcome_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class _FooterState extends State<Footer> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    final WelcomeBloc _welcome = Provider.of<WelcomeBloc>(context);
    _welcomeBloc = _welcome;
    // this._detectLastPage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0, horizontal: 30.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          this.stepper,
          this.nextArrow,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _detectLastPage() {
    // Here I've got inaccurate data

    print(this.widget.currentStep);
}
}
```

I have already tried some other hooks like Scheduler but maybe I did something wrong there.

```
SchedulerBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => this._detectLastPage());
```

It's called only once at the first build-up round and that's it. 
I lack an Angular hook here `AfterViewInit`. It would be handy here.

or `Mounted` in VueJS

---

That's the rest of my code if you'd like to see the whole picture.
If you have any suggestions on the architecture, structure or something else you are welcome. It's highly appreciated since I'm new to Flutter.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ui_flutter/routing.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'screens/welcome/welcome_bloc.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => WelcomeBloc()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        initialRoute: '/welcome',
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**welcome.dart** (my wrapper)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:ui_flutter/screens/welcome/welcome_bloc.dart';
import './footer.dart';
import './viewWrapper.dart';
import './header.dart';
// import 'package:ui_flutter/routing.dart';

class Welcome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomeState createState() => _WelcomeState();
}

class _WelcomeState extends State<Welcome> {
  WelcomeBloc _welcomeBloc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final WelcomeBloc _welcome = Provider.of<WelcomeBloc>(context);
    this._welcomeBloc = _welcome;
    print('Welcome: _welcome.currentPage - ${this._welcomeBloc.lastPage}');

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ViewerWrapper(),
            Footer(
              currentStep: _welcomeBloc.currentPage,
              totalSteps: 3,
              activeColor: Colors.grey[800],
              inactiveColor: Colors.grey[100],
            ),
            WelcomeHeader,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**welcomeBloc.dart** (my state via Provider)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WelcomeBloc extends ChangeNotifier {
  PageController _controller = PageController();
  int _currentPage;
  bool _lastPage = false;

  bool get lastPage => _lastPage;

  set lastPage(bool value) {
    _lastPage = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get currentPage => _currentPage;

  set currentPage(int value) {
    _currentPage = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  get controller => _controller;

  nextPage(Duration duration, Curves curve) {
    controller.nextPage(duration: duration, curve: curve);
  }
}
```

**footer.dart** (that's where I've problems with data at the very bottom of the code - _detectLastPage method)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:ui_flutter/screens/welcome/welcome_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class Footer extends StatefulWidget {
  final int currentStep;
  final int totalSteps;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color inactiveColor;
  final Duration duration;
  final Function onFinal;
  final Function onStart;

  Footer({
    this.activeColor,
    this.inactiveColor,
    this.currentStep,
    this.totalSteps,
    this.duration,
    this.onFinal,
    this.onStart,
  }) {}

  @override
  _FooterState createState() => _FooterState();
}

class _FooterState extends State<Footer> {
  final double radius = 10.0;
  final double distance = 4.0;
  Container stepper;
  Container nextArrow;
  bool lastPage;
  WelcomeBloc _welcomeBloc;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    final WelcomeBloc _welcome = Provider.of<WelcomeBloc>(context);
    _welcomeBloc = _welcome;
    this._detectLastPage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this._makeStepper();
    this._makeNextArrow();

    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0, horizontal: 30.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          this.stepper,
          this.nextArrow,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeCirle(activeColor, inactiveColor, position, currentStep) {
    currentStep = currentStep == null ? 0 : currentStep - 1;
    Color color = (position == currentStep) ? activeColor : inactiveColor;

    return Container(
      height: this.radius,
      width: this.radius,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: this.distance, right: this.distance),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          border: Border.all(color: activeColor, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
    );
  }

  _makeStepper() {
    List<Container> circles = List();

    for (var i = 0; i < widget.totalSteps; i++) {
      circles.add(
        _makeCirle(this.widget.activeColor, this.widget.inactiveColor, i,
            this.widget.currentStep),
      );
    }

    this.stepper = Container(
      child: Row(
        children: circles,
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeNextArrow() {
    this.nextArrow = Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              _welcomeBloc.controller.nextPage(
                duration: this.widget.duration ?? Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
              );
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onLastPage() {
    if (this.widget.onFinal != null) {
      this.widget.onFinal();
    }
  }

  _onFirstPage() {
    if (this.widget.onStart != null) {
      this.widget.onStart();
    }
  }

  _detectLastPage() {
    // Here I've got inaccurate data 

    int currentPage =
        this.widget.currentStep == null ? 1 : this.widget.currentStep;

    if (currentPage == 1 && this.widget.currentStep == null) {
      this._onFirstPage();
    } else if (currentPage == this.widget.totalSteps) {
      print('lastPage detected');
      setState(() {
        this.lastPage = true;
      });
      _welcomeBloc.lastPage = true;
      this._onLastPage();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        this.lastPage = false;
      });
      _welcomeBloc.lastPage = false;
    }
  }
}
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: There's too much code. Could you make a minimalistic  example?

Comment: @RémiRousselet, check it out, please, underneath all of that code. Some people require the whole code to see the whole picture. Did you mean minimalistic like that?

Comment: @RémiRoussele  Have any ideas on that problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am new to flutter as well, But I have learned about a few architecture patterns that have helped me build some apps.

Here is how I do it:

Create a `Provider` which holds the data for you in runtime. (It can be a `Bloc` in your case). Stick to one architecture, don't try to put providers and blocs in the same project. Both are used for state management and only using one would be a great practice.

Second, `Register` the providers using `ChangeNotificationProvider` or any other widgets which does a similar job of rebuilding the child widget when a data gets changed.

Third, Get the provider in the build method of the widget that is supposed to change when the value of the variable provider changes. This way only the concerned widget is redrawn.

For your case,
If you want to hide the header and footer once you reach the last page, you can declare a variable, let's say `isLastPage` set to `false` by default in your provider.
Next, wrap the widget, i.e. `header` and `footer` with `ChangeNotificationListner`

Now, let that widget decide what it has to do based on the value of `isLastPage`, either hide itself or show.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, this is the way I have done that but in my question, I was curious more about `didChangeDependencies`. I can easily access accurate data in any other components. I am just improving the skill and looking for the ways to solve different tasks in case I need them in the future. After `build` hook is a very important thing I guess (basing on my Angular and Vue experience) In this case above, I'm passing in the current page as a property there. I believe that's gonna be a good way to encapsulate logic in different views using Provider. Just learning in short...

Answer (score 0):

At the long run, I seem to have found `Mounted` lifecycle hook in Flutter which is implemented with the help of `Future.microtask`. Unlike `.addPostFrameCallback`:

```
SchedulerBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => this._detectLastPage());
```

Which is triggered only once like `InitState` (but only at the end of the build execution), `Future.microtask` can be placed inside `build` block and be invoked after every change and state update.

It doesn't solve the problem with the inaccurate state in `didChangeDependencies` hook but provides another way to perform post-build executions.

*Credits for the current solution to @Abion47*

**example**

```
Future.microtask(() => this._detectLastPage());
```